# React Native Axios upload image return Network Error on Android

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I tried to upload some data including an image to server using `Axios`.

**It's working perfectly on iOS**, but on Android, it returned **`Network Error`**

```
const data = new FormData();
        data.append('tag', tag.METHOD_TAG_UPLOAD_PHOTO);
        data.append('app_version', 1);
        data.append('os_type', tag.OS_TYPE);
        data.append('store_code', kodetoko);
        data.append('photo', {
            uri: image_picked.uri,
            type: 'image/jpeg',
            name: judul + ".jpg"
        });
```

I tried to search for solution elsewhere, they said that the problem is within the `type` of the `photo`'s object, it needs to use `image/jpeg` type. I'm using it but it still return **`Network Error`**. Please help.

Comment: If you're using localhost in the url, it will work on ios but not android, you should specify the server address for android

Comment: @MahdiN I'm not using localhost for the url. I use IP. Other request works fine too (get, post without image, etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios unable to upload file on android but working on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222377/axios-unable-to-upload-file-on-android-but-working-on-ios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open this dir 'android/app/src/debug/java/com/flatApp/ReactNativeFlipper.java'
2. Comment the line as per below code:

   ```
     NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
      new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
          // builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
        }
      });
   ```

Comment: This did not work for me, going to try upgrading my FLIPPER_VERSION to 0.41.0 as suggested below.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and accepted answer didn't work for me. Below is what helped me.

1. In android/app/src/main/java/com/{yourProject}/MainApplication.java
   comment the below line :

   ```
   initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())
   ```
2. In android/app/src/debug/java/com/{yourProject}/ReactNativeFlipper.java
   comment in line 43 :

   ```
   builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
   ```
3. Code for image upload :

   ```
   var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('UserId', 'abc@abc.com');
      formData.append('VisitId', '28596');
      formData.append('EvidenceCapturedDate', '09/10/2019 13:28:20');
      formData.append('EvidenceCategory', 'Before');
      formData.append('EvidenceImage', {
        uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? `file:///${path}` : `/private${path}`,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'image.jpg',
      });
      axios({
        url: UrlString.BaseUrl + UrlString.imageUpload,
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log('*****handle success******');
          console.log(response.data);

        })
        .catch(function (response) {
          console.log('*****handle failure******');
          console.log(response);
        });
   ```

Comment: Platform.OS === 'android' ? `file:///${path}` works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue as well and none of the above helped. Android is very specific about the file upload for the multipart/form data. If you have any of the file parameters wrong, **it will fail with "Network Error" and no other information** which is incredibly frustrating!

In order to get mine working, I started by following this example (from Expo, but nothing expo-specific here): https://github.com/expo/examples/blob/d86f50a710e3805494b458fae2595502d9afa7bc/with-formdata-image-upload/App.js

I recommend starting with that too and trying some different things here on this line: [where the file information is set for the requedst](https://github.com/expo/examples/blob/d86f50a710e3805494b458fae2595502d9afa7bc/with-formdata-image-upload/App.js#L172). I only modified this example `axios` instead of `fetch` for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

FLIPPER_VERSION=0.41.0

Update your Flipper_Version above or equal = 0.41.0

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, I guess this issue about Flipper Network.

For while, I commented initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())

in this file /android/app/src/main/java/com/{your_project}/MainApplication.java

NOW THIS IS WORKING PROPERLY

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in version 0.39.0. To upgrade, edit android > gradle.properties

#Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native

```
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.39.0  // edit this manually
```

Comment: This is an old version, the latest version is `0.103.0`
https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native

Answer (score 0):

add `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` in your headers will resolve the issue