# While uploading picture in Application getting network error?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native. I am trying to upload picture through API call but it's giving me Network Error. I have tried every possible solution but can't solve it.

```
let formData = new FormData();
    console.log(pickedImagePath);
    formData.append("filetoupload", {
      uri: pickedImagePath,
      type: "image/jpeg",
      name: pickedImagePath.split("/").pop(),
    } as any);
    const response = await api.post("upload-attachment", formData);
    console.log(response);
```

Image path is `file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540saad360%252Fsecurity_management_app/ImagePicker/785a2cff-f93e-458f-9c16-03496f1f22d9.jpg`

and error is:

```
  "data": null,
  "duration": 778,
  "headers": null,
  "ok": false,
  "originalError": [Error: Network Error],
  "problem": "NETWORK_ERROR",
  "status": null,
```

Comment: Set Content Type In Header "content type: multipart/form-data"

Comment: I have tried but still its giving network error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61288096/react-native-axios-upload-image-return-network-error-on-android


Try this Disable Flippers and Update In Androidmainfest android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the possible solutions but then I changed the package to react-native-image-picker from expo-image-picker now It is working perfectly.